# Django / Template folders in different app

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to create several apps in one Django project.

- Can I create a template folder in each app? or
- Should I add all my html's in one template folder in the main project app for each app?

[image: folder structure and settings]

If it is possible, how can I configure settings.py?

I tried but it just redirect to the same html. So I don't how to access several html in different template folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually create templates inside each app and inside the main project dir. Since you have `APP_DIRS=True` you don't have to define the path in `DIRS`. In `DIRS` you only have to define the paths that are outside the apps, for example the templates folder in the main project. You can have a configuration like this:

```bash
project
├── app1
│   └── templates
│       └── app1
│           └── index.html
├── app2
│   └── templates
│       └── app2
│           └── index.html
└── templates
    └── base.html
```

In the practice it is helpful to store general templates such as menus, layouts, etc, in the outside templates folder since those templates will be used more than once (extending or including them). And inside each app only templates that are related to the apps logic such as forms, info views, etc.

More about [templates configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates)

More about [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/)

Answer (score 0):

you have `APP_DIRS=True` so django template processor  will look in each registered app in folder `templates` for templates.

For app name spacing you would use in each app a path like

```
app_name/templates/app_name/
```